# Client Object Model equivalent of SPWeb.SiteLogoUrl

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

I can get the name, url and description of a site using [SP.Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee549149) but there is no logo property.

Is there a javascript COM equivalent to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitelogourl.aspx?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Microsoft have introduced the SiteLogoUrl property now within SPWeb in Office 365:

http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/uservoice-driving-improvements-sharepoint-api/ and https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6234945-make-the-sitelogourl-property-available-in-csom

The `<SiteLogoUrl>` element is emitted from the `_api/web` REST service.

Comment: Yup, they sure have!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no direct way to change the Site Logo from the Client Object Model.

However, you can change it through CSS by utilizing the `s4-titlelogo` class:

Paste the following code in your CSS file:

```
.s4-titlelogo{ 
background-image: url(/path/to/yourimage.png); 
background-position:left center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
} 
.s4-titlelogo > a > img{ 
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ideally I'd like to just know the logo path for the site, rather than needing to change it.

Comment: Ok. Then you can easily pickup the path with JavaScript/jQuery.
You just need to look into the <td> with the class .s4-titlelogo and then fetch the <a> tag inside it and then the <img> tag inside the <a> tag. The src of the <img> will be your logo path.

Comment: I should have stated my scenario more clearly. I'm building something like the first example in http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2012/02/28/metro-style-site-directory-for-sharepoint-using-emcascript.aspx, looping through web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser and displaying each site's name, description and link, but would also like to show its sitelogo. Looks like making a web control server-side is probably the way to go.