# Adding a logo to site and sub-site using the Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model

How do you add the url of a logo for the site and sub site using the client object model. This functionality can be found browsing the SP site.
**Site settings** -->**Title, Description, and Icon**-->**Logo URL and Description**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that using COM.

Possible duplicate of:
[Client Object Model equivalent of SPWeb.SiteLogoUrl](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40124/client-object-model-equivalent-of-spweb-sitelogourl)